# Pointer behaviour gives value as 1

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gcc

To be clear, I am aware of pointer to pointer concept in C and of dereferencing double, triple pointers. The only doubt I have is in the following program which I wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a;
    int* p;
    a=5;
    p=&a;
    int **q;
    printf("*p=%d\n",*p);
    printf("*q=%d\n",*q);
}
```

Now I know, the program is quite stupid and makes no sense, but that's  not the problem. The question is WHY?
Why is the Output like this:

```
*p=5
*q=1
```

Why is *q=1 on every run?
Also it is to keep in mind, if I now declare a ***r;
And add the following line:

```
printf("*r=%d\n",*r);
```

Now the output is :

```
*p=5
*q=-40821602 //garbage
*r=1
```

Now, *r=1. WHY?
Same goes for ****s. In that case, *q,*r is a garbage and *s=1. Why?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour, that's why.

Comment: Two things: You need to print `void *` pointers (casting is needed) using the `"%p"` format specifier; And you never initialize `q` meaning it dereferencing it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I am familiar with genric pointer. The question is what's with 1? Is displaying 1 an undefined behaviour?

Comment: Undefined Behavior (UB for short) usually means that any discussion about behavior is moot. However what happens here is that you're using uninitialized variables, whose values are *indeterminate* and seemingly random. It's this "seemingly random" values you see.

Comment: I would advise you to open it up in a debugger. It will likely print something different and/or seg fault but you might learn a bit about uninitialized pointers. Normally, they aren't written intentionally.

Comment: I am not seeing 1 as random, I have clearly mentioned 1 gets displayed on every run.

Comment: @doug I have tried using a debugger. No good

Comment: It isn't that strange for undefined behaviors to be consistent over time.  I've had some that were consistent for days, then something happened and the behavior changed.  Maybe I took an antivirus update, or a hotfix, who knows.  The fundamental answer to 'why' is 'because that pointer occupies a portion of memory that happens to have a '1' in it fairly consistently'.  Recompile with different flags and see if it changes (e.g., change debug settings or optimization settings.

Comment: If you open a debugger in assembly you can step through the machine instructions one by one which should provide clarity. Nothing you've seen surprises me at all and I'm not sure why you find it odd.

Comment: @doug I am using Immunity by default.

Comment: "Seemingly random" doesn't mean "really random". Also note what happens once you make a very small change, how suddenly you get something completely different? And talking about random: https://xkcd.com/221/ and https://imgur.com/gallery/uR4WuQ0

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I appreciate the comment. Failure to learn from mistakes makes it worse. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Printing `*p` prints the value of `a`, which is `5` as you are seeing.   Printing `*q` gives undefined behaviour in multiple ways: `q` is uninitialised so evaluating its value gives undefined behaviour, as does evaluating `*q` (it is necessary to evaluate `q` to evaluate `*q`), and then printing it introduces another round of undefined behaviour (`%d` format and the type of `*q` don't match).   When behaviour is undefined, any result is permitted.   Consistency of that result is permitted, but not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation of an uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior, and that is what you did. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) states the following on undefined behavior:

> **Undefined Behavior**:
>
> - undefined behavior - there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program. Examples of undefined behavior are memory accesses outside of array bounds, signed integer overflow, null pointer dereference, modification of the same scalar more than once in an expression without sequence points, access to an object through a pointer of a different type, etc. Compilers are not required to diagnose undefined behavior (although many simple situations are diagnosed), and the compiled program is not required to do anything meaningful.

Hence, you cannot expect anything meaningful coming out of your program. It may print 1, but it could also do anything else. In my case, for example, it simply crashed.

So the question *"why?"*  is simply not a valid question.